# DD-WRT: keep source IP after port forwarding

Tags: networking, iptables, dd-wrt

I just started using DD-WRT on my WNDR3700, but now all my incoming connections to a server inside the network get the same source IP as the router.

How can I change this back so I get the real source IP?

I have a pretty common setup with a fiber modem and the WNDR3700 as distribution.

Comment: Tell us more about your configuration. How did you set up port forwarding exactly?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I just used port range forwarding in the web interface. This is a dump of the nat table: http://pastebin.com/F2U0QW16

Comment: What's the SNAT rule for?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't added it. Must be something generated by the web interface...? Remove?

Comment: `MASQUERADE  0    --  anywhere             anywhere` probably isn't helping.

Comment: @Xyon: Changed MASQUERADEing to only external interface, didn't help.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Removed it, didn't help..

Answer (score 0):

Put the server in a DMZ.  Did your port forwarded services receive publicly sourced IP addresses beforehand?